# How to implement searchable lists in App Inventor

Tags: app-inventor

I want to implement a searchable list in my Road Safety app for the fines section. Fines will be distinguished based on whether they are parking violations, traffic violations and so on.
I found [this](https://05965789892836878813.googlegroups.com/attach/af1235efc65c88ab/listFilter.jpg?part=4&view=1&vt=ANaJVrGOgxSQNk4dwOMfh8LUrsH6sobJ1a3Kox5oMM3MWDiyCUbkHSR8LdmcRpiyGFoSZuk6yyjSD9033RHHDhSTPUefC6ixXO8B4OPiuQF3DtvJsCDu7VI) App Inventor 1 style block for implementing a list filter but it does not work very well. I'd like some help on which blocks to use and how its done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the built-in [Listpicker.FilterBar](http://ai2.appinventor.mit.edu/reference/components/userinterface.html#ListPicker)

> ShowFilterBar
>   Returns current state of ShowFilterBar indicating if Search Filter
>   Bar will be displayed on ListPicker or not

[image]

[image]

alternatively you can use some HTML/jQuery, see [this example](http://puravidaapps.com/listview.php)
[image]